# How can I split at line at an already existing point?

Tags: freecad

I've got a line with a point constrained to it.  I would like to split my line at the point.  The "Split Edge" tool will allow me to split the line anywhere but at that point.  How can I split at line at an existing point?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to 3D printing, I'm afraid, so it will be closed. Maybe try on [SE.Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)? If you can [edit] and change your question to being 3D printing related, then the question can be re-opened. Thanks. However, have a +1 anyway (that way it won't get deleted) :-)

Comment: Actually, seeing as you've answered the question yourself, could you accept the answer in 48 hours time? I'll re-open the question so that you can mark the answer as accepted (you won't be able to if it is closed).

Comment: I just want to give you a big giant thank you for suggesting an alternative stack exchange site.  You're the first mod I've ever seen do that!  Thank you.  I really hope you stick around :D

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for marking your answer as accepted - now that the question has an accepted answer it can not be auto-deleted (even after closing). I will close the question again now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Splitting at that specific point makes no sense because the split wouldn't be constrained to it at all.  It would just be confusing.

The way to do this is to split somewhere else on the line, then constrain the split point to the existing point.